# About text Filter and textWatcher in Android

Tags: android, filter, textwatcher

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfuN8.png)

I made an android app by using Textwatcher and Filter.
Whenever I search some text, this screen made me interrupted.. T_T
Why this box which is included in text is shown up?

Please help me T_T

Answer (score 0):

Actually it gives suggestion when you type.
To remove suggestion box add this property to EditText in xml layout

```
 android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

To remove mic icon from box add below property to EditText in xml layout

```
android:privateImeOptions="nm"    // "nm" : No Mic
```